# How to say "you are welcome"?

Tags: politeness

If someone thanks me in Latin, how should I respond?
I have been taught to reply *sodes*, but [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=sodes&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) does not seem to mention such use at all.
Did the Romans have any idiom for replying to "thank you"?
A direct translation of the English "you are welcome" is unlikely to work, and I don't want anything as heavy as *gratias tibi ago, quod gratias mihi egisti*.
Is *sodes* fine, but only a modern option?

Comment: *nihil est* 'it's nothing'

Comment: @Anonym That could work! Have you actually seen or heard it in use? I haven't, but that just proves my limited experience. If you can give a source for that option (your own experience is a source, too!), then I invite you to write that as an answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not a phrase which demands a response, at least not from the available evidence. Most instances of *gratias ago* do not have the thanked person respond at all, and I could only really find one exception.

In Cicero's *De Oratore* 2.268, we get this exchange:

> Arguta etiam significatio est, cum parva re et saepe verbo res obscura et latens inlustratur; ut, cum C. Fabricio P. Cornelius, homo, ut existimabatur, avarus et furax, sed egregie fortis et bonus imperator, gratias ageret, quod se homo inimicus consulem fecisset, bello praesertim magno et gravi **"nihil est, quod mihi gratias agas," inquit "si malui compilari quam venire".**
>
> There is also frequently acuteness shown, when something obscure and not commonly known is illustrated by a slight circumstance, and often by a single word; as when Publius Cornelius, a man, as was suspected, of a covetous and rapacious disposition, but of great courage and an able commander, thanked Caius Fabricius for having, though he was his enemy, made him consul, especially during a difficult and important war, **You have no reason to thank me, returned Fabricius, if I had rather be pillaged than sold for a slave.**

It's not a simple *nihil est*, but I think it gets the point across. But in this exchange, the thanked one minimized the actions, as if there actually was no reason to be thanked to begin with. This is different from the *de nada*s and *de rien*s that essentially mean, "It wasn't very difficult to do, but I appreciate the thanks anyway."

In Terence's *Phormio*, we get this exchange:

> *Nausistrata*: Phormio, at ego ecastor posthac tibi quod potero, quae voles faciamque et dicam.*Phormio*: Benigne dici'. *Na.*: **Pol meritumst tuom.**
>
> Nausistrata: Phormio, I by Castor henceforth I will do and speak for you whatever I can, whatever you wish. Phormio: Thanks! (Lit. You speak kindly.) Na. **By Pollux, you earned it.**

Here it might help to recognize that there were different ways of thanking someone, and this comes after kind words. I imagine it being similar to the English response, "You're too kind!" It's not really the formal thanks and it's not really an automatic "you're welcome."

There might be others, but there's certainly nothing consistent. Searching all possibilities is time consuming, but I think it speaks volumes that it's not something that is easily found (unlike the many ways of thanking someone); despite giving several ways of saying "Thanks!", Goodwin Beach's article "De Sermone Cotidiano" doesn't mention "You're welcome" in any way, though it might help remembering that *you're welcome* in its current form as a response to *thank you* was first attested only in 1907.<sup>1</sup>

I searched for *gratias* and *benigne* both, and while responses are often given, there isn't anything on par with English *you're welcome*, French *de rien*, or German *bitte*.

For modern speakers, I indeed have heard *nihil est*, *libet*, *precare/precamini*, and *flocci* all used, though you should always keep in mind just what you're being thanked for and its appropriate response. Even in English, for someone being publicly thanked for the service to the state, "you're welcome" is hardly appropriate.

<sub>1: Though certainly there were other responses, they just weren't "you're welcome."</sub>

Comment: Only Americans say "you're welcome".

Comment: @fdb And not all of us. It's also situational, but I think the younger crowd is largely abandoning the term.

Comment: @cmw says "*the younger crowd is largely abandoning the term*", and using something far worse. I've stopped saying "thanks" to waiters, etc., because the "No problem" response is so annoying. I thank them to recognize them as people and show appreciation that they are there doing something I wouldn't want to do; but It never even occurred to me that my expecting them to do the job they are paid for could have been a problem. "No problem" should be reserved for when one has gone out of their way to do something that they were under no obligation to do (e.g. push a stranger's car stuck in snow).

Comment: @RayButterworth I think you're reading that "no problem" too literally. I can guarantee that the majority are *not* thinking that deeply into their word choice. Just like no one is actually wishing "god be with ye!" when they say "good-bye."

Comment: @cmw, yes, I realize that to the speaker it means the same thing, but for people of my generation, it's still annoying. (We'll all die off soon, so it really will become no problem :-).  See [All Things Linguistic](https://allthingslinguistic.com/post/124189121619/no-problem-vs-youre-welcome), where one person hears it as I do, and another responds with the opposite view.

Comment: @RayButterworth Interestingly, I've actually read that before. I'm no stranger to bristling at new lingo, though I try to keep myself grounded: all languages change. I like the note that "you're welcome" itself only dates to the 20th century. It probably also would have been rude to someone who came of age in the late 19th century, let alone their parents!

Answer (score 3):

In @cmw's answer we see an exchange of the following kind:

> A thanks B for a compliment or a display of esteem/affection
>
> B replies with *Meritum est tuum*, maybe embellished with a preceding interjecton like *pol*

I propose a general formula to cover (all?) other cases, provided a reply is appropriate in the first place:

> A thanks B for some kind of help or advice
>
> B replies with *Gaudeo quod tibi profuerim* or *Gaudeo me tibi profuisse* "Glad I was helpful (to you)"

There don't seem to be instances of these phrases in classical sources, but a quick Google search shows that numerous Latin grammar books have reported them from early 19th century on, so I would use them casually.

Answer (score 2):

SAW THIS ON QUORA:
John Kerpan, Master of Latin and the Classical Humanities
Answered 3 years ago · Author has 1.4K answers and 1.7M answer views
If you want to reply to “Thank you” like a Roman, use “libenter”. It means “willingly” or “gladly”.

Comment: Thanks for sharing that answer. Can you provide a link to the response on Quora? It can help to have that in the event there's further discussion or information from the original source.

Comment: @Adam Traupman, in his dictionary under "Welcome", lists *libenter* as meaning "you are welcome".