# Translation question: We fixed it; you’re welcome

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

I’m trying to find a translation for what would become something like a Friday patch. It’s a fun way to poke.

> “We fixed it.”
>
> “You’re welcome.”

From what I’ve found so far it would be something like:

> “Emendavi”
>
> “Nihil Est”

I don’t know how to conjugate the first word though so it makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say a more appropriate word for repair in your context is *reficio*, rather than *emendo*. For what I can see in [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=emendo&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), the latter seem to be used more abstractly, or for non-physical things. Conversely, *reficio* seem to refer to physical things, including examples like walls, gates, weapons, and so on. [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=reficio) also gives it the translation "repair", which *emendo* does not have. Another option could be *resarcio*, which is used with clothes, and can be translated as "to patch", which is perhaps more analog to what a software update is.

So, for *reficio*, the conjugation in your example would be *[refecimus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/refecimus#Latin)*. For *resarcio*, it would be *[resarsimus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/resarsimus#Latin)*.

Finally, "You are welcome" is an expression, so translation is more complex. There is already [a dedicated post](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/4371/how-to-say-you-are-welcome) on this site about it, suggesting there is not a native equivalent, but *nihil est* might be a decent modern compromise. Now, *nihil est* means "it is nothing". So in the context of a finished past action (it was fixed and the problem is no more, hopefully), it is better to use the perfect tense: *Nihil fuit*.

Comment: This is awesome thank you! The thing I liked about emendavi is that it’s “to makes something better” and I think that’s what I was going for, not fix in the sense of repair, but like taking someone else’s product and fixing it, and making it better.

Answer (score 1):

There is one case where Cicero says *"gaudeo"* 'I am happy (to have helped).'

If that's OTT there are three milder terms for "Fine!"
*licet,* 'That's OK.'
*placet,* lit. 'It pleases.'(I think that's what Her Majesty says when she approves a law)
*[lubet,](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.10:1030.lewisandshort)* lit. 'I'm glad.' also *libenter* 'gladly' (used both colloquially (Plautus, Terence), and formally (Cicero)

[lucet, in an earlier post was apparently a misprint for *lubet* in the dictionary]

As they are impersonal verbs there is no need to alter the endings: suits all occasions.

Comment: Don't impersonal verbs still mark tense and aspect, just not person or number?

Comment: Ah, yes; suits all occasions within the context of "a fun way to poke." English "you were welcome" subjunctive "may you be welcome" don't figure. BUT they are possible.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a more appropriate answer for the linked post (about "you're welcome") rather than this one?